# English Safrut Shiurim

Tags: product-recommendation, english, adult-learning, safrus

I will admit that my searches in this area have been somewhat cursory, but is there a resource (something like [YUTorah.org](http://YUTorah.org)) for anglophone shiurim on safrut? Most of the shiurim I've found are in Yiddish, which I do not understand.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this course from [Web Yeshiva](http://mastery.webyeshiva.org/safrut-certification/), a while ago. It is in English, and it does seem thorough enough for a beginner. It describes what you will learn as well as what materials you need.

Comment: If you think of taking the course but have trouble getting the materials in your area, let me know. I'll try to get it to you.